# Cutting board algo

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a rectangular board of MxN dimensions which needs to be cut into square peices of 1x1 size. Each of these squares has some value and the cost of cutting is the sum of the values of all the squares involved in the cut. I want to find the minimum possible cost.

**Example**

Say we have 2x3 board and the values of square peices are given in matrix like:

```
2 7 5
1 9 5
```

Now if we first make a horizontal cut the cost will be (2+7+5+1+9+5=29), and we will get two smaller reactangular board like:

`2 7 5` and `1 9 5`

Next we cut 1,9 and 5 (cost=1+9+5=15), then 2,7 and 5 (cost=2+7+5=14). So we have the following boards:

`2 7` , `5`, `1 9`, `5`

After this we cut 1 and 9 (cost=1+9=10), then 2 and 7 (cost=2+7=9). And we have the following squares left:

`2` , `7`, `5`, `1`, `9`, `5`

Now we will stop as all the remaining peices are 1x1 only.

So the total cost is 77. Now this is just one of the ways which gives the minimum cost. There are other ways to cut the board which may give same or higher cost.

So, how can I find the minimum cost? Thanks for help!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: can you elaborate on how the cutting works?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous i understood where to cut first, like since we are taking the sum of the values of the squares involved, therefore we should first separate bigger values, so that they dont come again in sum, but i am not sure how to keep track of the board at any given time, like what cuts have been made and what more are still to be made

Comment: Does `all the squares involved` mean `all squares of the current piece of board`? That is the very first cut will always cost the sum of all cells of the board?

Comment: @dangee1705 I have edited the question so that the example is more clear now

Comment: @Poolka yes you are absolutely right. I have edited the question so that the example is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

This has taken me a while to come up with, and isn't very efficient, but for small puzzles it should be fine.

```
class Piece:
    def __init__(self, data, w, h):
        self.data = data
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

    def cut_vertically(self, x):
        a = Piece([v for i, v in enumerate(self.data) if i % self.w <= x], x + 1, self.h)
        b = Piece([v for i, v in enumerate(self.data) if i % self.w > x], self.w - x - 1, self.h)
        s = sum(self.data)
        return a, b, s

    def cut_horizontally(self, y):
        a = Piece([v for i, v in enumerate(self.data) if i < self.w * (y + 1)], self.w, y + 1)
        b = Piece([v for i, v in enumerate(self.data) if i >= self.w * (y + 1)], self.w, self.h - y - 1)
        s = sum(self.data)
        return a, b, s

    def generate_cuts(self):
        for x in range(self.w - 1):
            yield self.cut_vertically(x)
        for y in range(self.h - 1):
            yield self.cut_horizontally(y)

def scores(p):
    if p.w == 1 and p.h == 1:
        yield 0

    for a, b, s in p.generate_cuts():
        for s1 in scores(a):
            for s2 in scores(b):
                yield s + s1 + s2

p = Piece([2, 7, 5, 1, 9, 5], 3, 2)

min_score = None
for score in scores(p):
    if not min_score or score < min_score:
        min_score = score

print(score)
```

It doesn't have any error checking, so you have to make sure your `Piece` is setup correctly, but I hope it is enough for your needs.